# validate dynamically added textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

In the below code how to validate for null values for only the dynamically added text box i.e,r_score1,r_score2.........

```
  <script>
   function validate()
   {
      //How to validate the r_Score.. textfields
   }
  $(document).ready(function() {
   for(var i=0;i< sen.length;i++)
   {
     row += '<input type="text" name="r_score'+i+'" id="r_score'+r_count+'" size="8" />';
    }
   $('#details').append(row);
   });
   </script>
   <div id="details"><input type="text" name="score' id="score" size="8" /></div>
  <input type="button" value="Save" id="print" onclick="javascript:validate();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the text boxes a class name and use class selector

```
function validate()
   {
      var boxes = $("#details input:text.classname");
      boxes.each(function(){
          var currentVal = $(this).val();
          // do your validation here
      });
   }
```

Comment: Rahul let me ask u this,when is id to be used and when is class to be used?

Comment: Since your ids are generated dynamically you have to use attribute comparison operator to get all the elements with the particular pattern. So in this case I think it would be better to use a class so that you can identify the elements.

Comment: If you know the exact id then use id selector, since it is the fastest one. Otherwise use a combination of tag and class selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#details input[name^='r_score']").each(function(nr){

    if($(this).val() === "") alert("Field "+(nr+1)+" is empty");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler for dynamically added content.